# Access query with no returned results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query in Access and would like to know if it were possible to use the `where not exists` clause to display a specific text for each field when there are no returned rows.

Example query:

```
Select Field1, Field2, Field3  
From TableA  
Where Field1 = "test";
```

If there are no returned results I would like the following to return:

```
Field1 = "test"  
Field2 = "not provided"  
Field2 = "not provided"
```

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM Table
WHERE ID=3
UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT "None","None" FROM AnyTableithAtLeastOneRow
WHERE 3 NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Table)
```

Comment: This will return no rows if Table is empty, won't it?

Comment: You can use any table, including system tables, which are guaranteed not to be empty.

Comment: Would I have to create the table AnyTableithAtLeastOneRow with the values i want for this to work?

Comment: @Rick No, it means exactly what it says, you can use any table that is always sure to have at least one row. You can use the main table (Table above), if that suits.

Comment: Having a hard time porting this to Access, since I am using this on a sub-report that is linked by the ID field (not originally stated) to the parent report.

Comment: The above is in Access. If you want this for a report, it would probably be better to VBA to, say, show and hide a textbox with  `Child.Report.HasData`

Comment: Access says the query is too complex as a record source

Comment: This would not be the usual method of solving the problem you are experiencing. A more usual way would be to set the visibility of a control. This could be a subform with a dummy record.

Comment: Really nice logic. Specially that `DISTINCT` keyword. Alternatively, we can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` condition instead of `WHERE 3 NOT IN`. :)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do what you're asking is:

```
Select Field1, isnull(Field2, 'Not Provided'), isnull(Field3, 'Not Provided')
```

*edit*
whoops, you're using Access, in that case the equivalent function is "nz" (what?! :p)

```
Select Field1, nz(Field2, 'Not Provided'), nz(Field3, 'Not Provided')
```

Comment: It is not even null, no rows are returned, yesno?

Comment: As a mater of curiosity, has anyone tried this in Access? Because for me, no rows are returned at all. In other words, Nz does not help when there are no rows.

Comment: This will return nothing if there is nothing in the table. If there is rows in the data which have empty fields, it will return these error values.